# Windows 7 resets monitor positions after ending task on a full-screen app

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, control-panel

When I end task on a full-screen app, usually a game, or when it crashes to desktop, the monitor positions and orientations reset to default.  This is getting old, *fast*. Is there a simple way to save and restore monitor positions and orientations in a hurry?

Note: I submitted feedback on this both in the beta and RC, both were closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: What is the game?  And is it truly reseting, or is the game leaving the video adapter in a bad state (more likely)?

Comment: What do you mean by position and orientation?  Do you have your monitor at a 90* angle?

Comment: I'm not surprised they were closed, I wouldn't be able to reproduce that behaviour myself and have not noticed any problems like this so far. What monitors? What game? What orientations? What graphics card?

Comment: @Avery: Happens on multiple games (starcraft, half life 2, supreme commander, NES Emulators - Anything.) Not sure how it happens; looks like a normal video mode switch. Event logs show no relevant detail.

@Chris: Yes, two of the six are in Portrait mode. Position means physical location relative to each other.

@Stefan: Two Dells, an HP, two Westinghouses, and a Viewsonic. 2 portrait, 4 landscape. Three ATI Radeon X1650 Pro's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in Windows they aren't willing to allocate the resources to fix. Adding an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking if there are newer ATI video drivers available for Windows 7?  The orientation issue could be driver related.

Comment: Have updated to both the newest Windows Update driver as well as the newest one at ati.amd.com.  Both gave me video problems so I reverted.